# How to detect the Context of the message sent from Dialogflow to Python back end?

Tags: python-3.x, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using the following `detect_intent` function:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'private_key.json'

DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'kuku-lulu'

DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

SESSION_ID = 'me'

def detect_intent(text):

    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)

    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text = text, language_code = DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text = text_input)

    try:

        response = session_client.detect_intent(session = session, query_input = query_input)

    except InvalidArgument:

        raise

    # print("Query text:", response.query_result.query_text)

    # print("Detected intent:", response.query_result.intent.display_name)

    # print("Detected intent confidence:", response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence)

    # print("Fulfillment text:", response.query_result.fulfillment_text)

    return {'sc': session_client, 'intent_name': response.query_result.intent.display_name}
```

How can I also detect the context from Dialogflow?

Comment: @prisoner can you please help?

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of people who can help.

Comment: @Prisoner can you please share the possible answer if you know how to solve it?

Comment: Does the answer I posted below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response.query_result.output_context` field should be an array of currently active contexts, each one being a [Context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions.contexts#Context) object.

You can read this information and send it back as the input contexts for the next request.